# How to handle recurring/repeating event in Spring Boot JPA

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have an app in which I compute the common journey between different users. Common journey are then meant to be taken together (like blablacar does for example).

In my app, I save user's journey between two distances. I simply compare multiple journey's `pointA` and `pointB` to find which journeys are common.

This is a basic structure of my responsible entity.

```java
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "PJ_JOURNEY")
public class Journey {

   @Id
   private UUID id;

   @CreationTimestamp
   private Timestamp creationDate;

   @OneToOne
   private Point pointA;

   @OneToOne
   private Point pointB;

   // Getters & Setters & Others...
}
```

Now I should compare also using time at each of these points. The complete requirement is to be able to save directly a recurring journey's event in the database (e.g so that one can register that he travels only every monday, tuesday and wednesday).

I've updated the structure with `timeAtA` and `timeAtB` to know when the user in his journey will leave the point A and arrive the point B, and also added a collection of days to know on which day the journey-event will occur:

```java
   @CreationTimestamp
   private Timestamp timeAtA;

   @CreationTimestamp
   private Timestamp timeAtB;

   @ElementCollection(targetClass = TravelRepetitionDays::class)
   @CollectionTable(name="repetition_days")
   @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
   @Column(name="day")
   private Set<TravelRepetitionDays> days;
```

*Problem*: How do I search using SQL and JPA using days and time at each point.

Thanks!

Comment: Question in not clear enough to me so that i cannot help

Comment: I've update the question and now there should be enough explanations

Comment: What is the problem, exactly? What query are you trying to create? What have you tried so far?